# Trying to find all files in a directory that start with 4 numbers and insert those 4 number into a text file

Tags: powershell

I'm completely stuck, I haven't messed with powershell in a while and am struggling to figure out based on online texts what I am doing wrong. I just want to be able to generate a text file to grab all the files in one directory and write the first 4 numbers into a notepad (if possible, i would like it to not write the same 4 numbers into a notepad more than once)

but here is what I have and it was at least writing file names earlier but I changed something and it just broke

```
 $files = Get-ChildItem source |
 ? { $_.Name.SubString(0,4) -match "[0- 9] " } |
 select Name | Out-File -path outputpath
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[0- 9]` should be `[0-9]` (and the whole regex should really be `'^[0-9]{4} '`), but there's no need for post-filtering [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)'s output with a [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) call, given that you can directly use a [wildcard expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) in the (positionally implied) `-Path` argument:

```sh
(Get-ChildItem 'source/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] *').Name.Substring(0,4) |
  Select-Object -Unique > outputpath
```

<sup>Note that I've replaced `Out-File -path outputpath` with `> outputpath` for concision; `>` is (in effect) an alias for [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file)</sup>